# React Navigation crashes when rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting an error while rendering navigation container.

I just installed the project with the step by step getting started guide.
but still I'm getting an error.

here is my Code:

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <NavigationContainer></NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "instagram_clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The error i am getting:
abi44_0_0.com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Failed to execute 'importScripts'
on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://192.168.1.23:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=false&minify=false' failed to load

Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://192.168.1.23:19000/node_modules%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false' failed to load

Am i installing something wrong?

Comment: I think you also have to define screens